# How to have different layouts per category?

Tags: jekyll

How to have different layouts for post categories?

For example, if i have "toys" and "swords" as categories for my posts, i'd like the page listing "toys" to have a different layout than the page listing "swords". Even better would be to have a default "products" layout if the post is in a category that does not have its own layout. Any ideas on how to implement this using jekyll?

Comment: Do you want custom layout for the page listing all posts in one specific category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the semantic of your documents will not change between categories I think you have to address that with CSS.

**sword_list.html**

```
---
category: sword
layout: product_listing
title: swords list
---
{% include product_listing_loop %}
```

**_includes/product_listing_loop.html**

```
<div class="{{page.category}}">
<ul>
{% for post in categories[page.category] %}
  <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

You can even use the page.category as a class on the body element in the main template.

Edit : If your really need to have a different markup you can try :

**sword_list.html**

```
---
category: sword
layout: product_listing
title: swords list
---
{% assign include_name = 'category_' | append: {{page.category}} %} 
{% include {{include_name}} %}
```

This will call `_includes/category_sword.html`

Comment: That sounds good, (categories[page.category] was nice!) but what if i need a different markup for each category?